# Reset ajax jquery generated div on ajax->submit() w/ cakephp

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, post

I have a simple ajax/jquery search form which generates the results in a div which is rendered by a controller.. If I resubmit the form, the results below are just replaced, they are not removed first while my loader displays..

I am wondering if anyone knows a way to reset the result div on each submit, so that it clears out and then displays the new results fresh as opposed to just a replace of the existing results.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have any Code?

Comment: Yup I have all the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tim,
I was not able to get the jQuery processing, so I used Prototype in my $ajax->submit $options like:

Prototype function (not inside options):

```
function clearOnClick() {
$('ajax_search_div').update();
}
```

In $options array:

...

```
 'before' => 'Event.observe(\'ajaxSubmitForm\', \'submit\', clearOnClick());',
```

...

I use the callback option of .observe to call the above function.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no option for this within the Ajax-Helper of CakePHP you would have to do that manually with jQuery when your form gets submitted.

```
$('#idOfYourForm').submit(function() {
    $('#idOfYourSearchResults').html('');
});
```

Don't use `remove` because this would remove the entire div which you need for populating the results of the ajax-request.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I will give this a shot and let you know what happens.